# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: messages is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

**In this file, I got this error.** `Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: messages is undefined` **(I'm building and NEXT app)**

[image]

**Please help me to solve this error. messages will be loaded with postman, Problem with this page. The query I have been checked with postman and data fetched succesfully**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { HiPlusSm } from 'react-icons/hi';
import router from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

const MessageList = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    //TODO check how to get the current user id - localstorage.getitem()
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMessages = async () => {
            await axios
                .get('/api/messages/getMessages', {
                    params: { sender: '62de47ab819e077df87d0661' },
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    setTimeout(() => setMessages(result.data.messages), 1000);
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (!result.data.messages) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        };

        fetchMessages();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={'bg-gray-100'}>
            <div className="mx-auto py-4 px-4 pt-8 md:max-w-4xl">
                <div className={'w-full bg-white p-5 shadow-sm'}>
                    <div className="mt-4 px-1">
                        <Link href="/inbox/new">
                            <button
                                className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-100 px-4 py-1.5 text-xs font-medium text-susty shadow-sm hover:border-susty hover:bg-susty hover:text-white`}
                            >
                                <HiPlusSm className="mr-2 h-5 w-5 items-center" />
                                New Message
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    <div className="w-full overflow-auto bg-white shadow md:h-[410px] xl:h-[630px]">
                        <div className="h-full w-full">
                            <div className={'mt-10 flex flex-col-reverse'}>
                                {messages.map((msg) => (
                                    <div key={msg} id={msg}>
                                        <span>{msg.message}</span>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MessageList;
```

Comment: Why are using `setTimeout` in the `then` function?

Comment: since the first `.then((result) => {` returns undefined, of course the `result` in the next `.then((result) => {` is undefined ... though, the error should be regarding reading `data` not reading `messages` - guess the error is something else